# A pig in flight collects coins. I do not know how to randomly generate coins so that they do not overlap. Thank you very much

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var water = new Image();
var cn = new Image();
var cnBottom  = new Image();
var coins  = new Image();
var xPos = 100
var yPos =300
var vMov = 1
var hMov =1
var xCoins
var yCoins
var moneyX = []
var moneyY = []
var i = 0
bird.src = "img/pig.png";
bg.src = "img/фон 1.png";
cn.src = "img/пушка 1.png";
cnBottom.src = "img/пушка 2.png";
water.src = "img/вода большая.png";
coins.src = "img/монета.png";
//in this function i check distanse between two coins
function condOfEq(e) {
    var n
    var g = 0
    var e
    while (n!=true) {
        if (g >= 4) {
            moneyX.pop(), moneyY.pop(),n=true, e =false
        }
        let x = moneyX[g]
        let y = moneyY[g]
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.abs(((xCoins - x) ** 2) + ((yCoins - y) ** 2))) >= 58) {
            /*ctx.drawImage(coins, moneyX[i], moneyY[i])*/
            n=true,e=true
        } else {n=false}
        g++

    }
    return e

}
function draw() {
    randomG()

    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0)
    ctx.drawImage(water,0, cvs.height - water.height, 1270,127);
    /*ctx.drawImage(coins,xCoins,yCoins)*/
    /*xPos += hMov*/
    /*requestAnimationFrame(draw);*/
}

//here i radomize x and y value and put them into massive


function randomG(){
    while (moneyY.length<5,i<4){
        function drawCoinsX(){
            return Math.floor (Math.random() * (800-400) + 400)
        }
        xCoins = drawCoinsX()
        moneyX.push(xCoins)
        console.log(moneyX)

        function drawCoinsY(){
            return Math.floor (Math.random() * (400-300)+300 )
        }
        yCoins = drawCoinsY()
        moneyY.push(yCoins)
        console.log(moneyY)

        if (moneyY.length>1) {

            condOfEq()

            if (condOfEq(true)){
                ctx.drawImage(coins,moneyX[i],moneyY[i]),i++
            }


        }
        else {ctx.drawImage(coins,10,15),i++}


    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1270" height="590"></canvas>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <script src="class.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! I just started to learn programming.Sorry for so ugly code. And thank you for help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand your question. Do you get an error? What is the expected output?

Comment: No, They just don't draw. Without error.

Comment: Coins should appear in random places, but not lying on top of each other